# Remove redundant or duplicate tuples in Ruby array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Imagine the following Ruby array:

```
[9, 9, 5, 5, 5, 2, 9, 9]
```

What's the easiest way of removing redundant tuples, producing an output like the following:

```
[9, 5, 2, 9]
```

`uniq` is not correct because it's examining the entire array. The ordering of the input is important and must be kept. Is there a straightforward approach to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, so many great answers! Thanks everybody! Arup was first in and his answer is most concise, so I'll go with that one!

Comment: I think you meant "consecutive repeated" values, not "redundant" or "duplicate". Removing "redundant" or "duplicate" values would be a different problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd do using [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk)

```
2.0.0-p0 :001 > a = [9, 9, 5, 5, 5, 2, 9, 9]
 => [9, 9, 5, 5, 5, 2, 9, 9] 
2.0.0-p0 :002 > a.chunk { |e| e }.map(&:first)
 => [9, 5, 2, 9]
```

Comment: I like this. Do mind that Enumerable#chunk was first introduced in Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: @JaapHaagmans I started from Ruby 1.9.3 my Ruby journey. So I can't answer you.. You can check the documentation series from the official sites.

Comment: It wasn't a question. Just a warning. This can't be used when using Ruby 1.8.7, for instance (many people still use 1.8.7).

Comment: Ha! Good solution! Works even with any types of elements in Enum instance! a = Object.new; [a, 1, 5, 5, a, a, 7, 7].chunk { |e| e }.map(&:first) => [a, 1, 5, a, 7] Great!

Answer (score 6):

I would do it like

```
b = [];
a.each { |n| b << n if b.last != n }
```

and `b` is the result

only one array scan is needed

Comment: @ArupRakshit `b` is the result (see edit). Do you think there is a chance of a `nil` introduced in `b` ?

Comment: As you write it last.. So my answer is No..:)

Comment: It would look cleaner with `inject`

Comment: If the first elements of `a` are `nil` they will be omitted from `b`. This can be fixed by initializing `b = [a[0]];`

Comment: @theTinMan true. fixed

Answer (score 2):

I like Arup's answer best, but in case you want a method that is compatible with versions that don't have `chunk` you can do

```
a = [9, 9, 5, 5, 5, 2, 9, 9]
a.inject([a[0]]) { |b,c| b.last == c ? b : b << c }
# => [9, 5, 2, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my version:

```
a.each_with_object([]) { |el, arr| arr << el if arr.last != el }
#=> [9, 5, 2, 9]
```

Comment: No reason here for me not to give it a up hit.. so I did.. :)

Answer (score 1):

For those who land on this question looking to remove "redundant" values, the OP is trying to remove "repeated consecutive" values, not "redundant" or "duplicate" values and used the wrong word. They are different situations.

For clarification, removing redundant or duplicate values would be:

```
asdf = [9, 9, 5, 5, 5, 2, 9, 9]
asdf.uniq # => [9, 5, 2]
```

Or:

```
asdf & asdf # => [9, 5, 2]
```

Or:

```
require 'set'
asdf.to_set.to_a # => [9, 5, 2]
```

And, yes, I know the OP is asking for a different result. This is to show the answer for the question that was asked, *NOT* what what would meet the desired output. For that see the selected answer.

Comment: Correct output should be `[9, 5, 2, 9]`

Comment: I *KNOW* that. I'm pointing out that the OP isn't using the correct terminology. If they want to remove *REDUNDANT* values, the result will be the code I show.

Answer (score 0):

This is to show how you could use an enumerator directly, with the methods [Enumerator#next](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Enumerator#peek](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek).

```
def purge_conseq_dups(arr)
  return arr if arr.empty?
  enum = arr.to_enum
  a = []
  loop do
    e = enum.next
    a << e unless e == enum.peek
  end
  a << arr.last
end

asdf = [9, 9, 5, 5, 5, 2, 9, 9] 
purge_conseq_dups(asdf) #=> [9, 5, 2, 9]
```

- When `e` is the last element of the enumerator `enum`, `enum.peek` raises a `StopInteration` exception which is rescued by [Kernel#loop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop), which responds by breaking out of the loop.  At that point all that remains is to append the last element of `arr` to `a`.
- We could write `a << e` rather than `a << arr.last`, provided we initialize `e` prior to the loop (e.g., `e = nil`) so that the variable will be in scope in the last line.